# Test Kitchen with existing chef node

Tags: chef-infra, knife, test-kitchen

If I already have a node provisioned using `$ knife bootstrap...` and in my list of servers `$ knife list`, can I just point kitchen to that node and have it converge so I can then run verify on it?

Answer (score 1):

Kind of, but that’s really not what Test Kitchen is for. What you probably want is to use the `inspec` CLI tool directly.